# Theorem on triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let a triangle $ABC$ be given (figure below). Let us take an arbitrary point $P$, inside the triangle. Let us now join $P$ with the vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, so as to obtain segments $i=AP$, $j=BP$ and $k=CP$. I want to prove that if for any point $P$ it is possible to construct a triangle having its sides equal to $i$, $j$, and $k$, respectively, then the original triangle $ABC$ is equilateral.

[image: figure 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To form a triangle, values $i,j,k$ have to satisfy equations:
$$
i + j \geq k
$$
$$
i + k \geq j
$$
$$
j + k \geq i
$$

If $P \rightarrow A$, then $i \rightarrow 0$, $j \rightarrow AB$ and $k \rightarrow AC$. The inequalities above then imply that $AB \geq AC$ and $AC \geq AB$, which means that $AB=AC$. In a similar way one can prove that $AB=BC$.

Comment: I think there is a mistake here. In any triangle, the sum of two sides is greater than the remaining one (Elements, I, 20). So $i+j$ cannot be equal to $k$, and similarly for the other inequalities.

Comment: In a triangle $i+j>k$, but after taking a limit it leads to $lim(i)+lim(j) \geq lim(k)$

Comment: @DavideC  It is sometimes confusing.  To some people, a degenerate triangle is a triangle.  To some, it is not.  So, the two of you may have different definitions.  And atarasenko's solution works fine even if you don't count degenerate triangles as triangles.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, Atarasenko's solution works fine, now I see.